# How to return async data in reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, reducers

I'm getting some data from back-end of my app, but I have a hard time returning state properly.
Code:

```
if (action.type === actionTypes.getList) {
    const id = action.payload.userId;
    
    Axios.post(`${apiUrl}/lists`, {
        userId: id,
    })
        .then((response) => {
            const newLists = response.data;
            return { ...listState, lists: newLists };
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log("There has been error: ", e);
        });
}
```

With this state's reducer state is undefined, and I get it since I'm not returning anything from main If statement.

```
if (action.type === actionTypes.getList) {
    const id = action.payload.userId;

    const newLists = Axios.post(`${apiUrl}/lists`, {
        userId: id,
    })
        .then((response) => {
            const res = response.data;
            return res
        })
        .catch((e) => {
            console.log("There has been error: ", e);
        });
    return { ...listState, lists: newLists };
}
```

Here my reducer state is empty object and I get Promise { : "pending" } in console. Is there some way how to call that main return statement after the async function is done? Or any other way of solving this problem?

Comment: You can't wait for the result of an async inside a sync function. Thus you should make the surrounding function async too and either return or await the Promise you get from `Axios.post()` in your first snippet.

Comment: You need to dispatch a new event when the data arrives asynchronously

Comment: yep, I managed to do that, thank you for your advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so Ive figured it out... I had to re-write my code in context as well:

**listContext.js:**

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (userId) {
        Axios.post(`${apiUrl}/lists`, {
            userId: userId,
        }).then((response) => {
            const lists = response.data;
            dispatch({ type: actionTypes.getListData, payload: { lists: lists } });
        });
    }
}, [userId]);
```

**listReducer.js:**

```
if (action.type === actionTypes.getListData) {
    const { lists } = action.payload;
    console.log(lists);

    return { ...listState, lists: lists };
}
```

Basically getting data in context and after the data arrives calling dispatch and returning new state from reducer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll advise you to use Redux actions for any middleware logic between the reducer and the dispatch function.
see https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-3-state-actions-reducers
I'm not sure what's wrong with your code tho...